# DC/OS service development with Akka

Tags: akka, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

First of all, I'm new to DC/OS ...

I installed DC/OS locally with Vagrant, everything worked fine. Then I installed Cassandra, Spark and I think to understand the container concept with Docker, so far so good.

Now it's time to develop an Akka service and I'm a little bit confused how I should start. The Akka service should simply offer a HTTP REST endpoint and store some data to Cassandra.

So I have my DC/OS ready, and Eclipse in front of me. Now I would like to develop the Akka service and connect to Cassandra from outside DC/OS, how can I do that? Is this the wrong approach? Should I install Cassandra separately and only if I’m ready I would deploy to DC/OS?

Because it was so simple to install Cassandra, Spark and all the rest I would like to use it for development as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While slightly outdated (since it's using DC/OS 1.7 and you should be really using 1.8 these days) there's a very nice tutorial from [codecentric](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/04/smack-stack-hands/) that should contain everything you need to get started:

1. It walks you through setting up DC/OS, Cassandra, Kafka, and Spark
2. It shows how to use Akka reactive streams and the [reactive kafka extension](https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka) to ingest data from Twitter into Kafka
3. It shows how to use Spark to ingest data Cassandra

Another great walkthrough resource is available via [Cake Solutions](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/smack-stack-on-dcos):

1. It walks you through setting up DC/OS, Cassandra, Kafka, and Marathon-LB (a load balancer)
2. It explains service discovery for Akka
3. It shows how to expose a service via Marathon-LB

Comment: Which is? Answers with links only are not allowed on SO unless quotes are used for main points? Mind elaborating on the main points, Michael?